# open app in mobile safari browser

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I have been using the uiwebview for a app that consists a index.html,css and javascript files.I'd like to do away with the uiwebview and open the app in the safari browser instead.All source files are located within the app bundle.Is it possible and if so can someone point me in the rite direction.Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: You want to open your app (files from your app) in Safari? Or you want that your app open link in Safari?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the iPhone OS, any application runs in a sandbox environment, which means that it cannot access files (like your index.html,css etc) that resides in other applications bundles.

Comment: Yes I thought this may be the case.Too bad,would really like to be able to use the browser functions as part of the app.It would save a lot of object c coding to get the end result.Would be great if apple would instate this functionality but i guess there are security concerns involved.thanks for your help.